# Run-length decompression using C++

Tags: c++, compression, run-length-encoding

I have a text file with a string which I encoded.

Let's say it is: `aaahhhhiii kkkjjhh ikl wwwwwweeeett`

Here the code for encoding, which works perfectly fine:

```
void Encode(std::string &inputstring, std::string &outputstring)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inputstring.length(); i++) {
        int count = 1;
        while (inputstring[i] == inputstring[i+1]) {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        if(count <= 1) {
            outputstring += inputstring[i];
        } else {
            outputstring += std::to_string(count);
            outputstring += inputstring[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Output is as expected: `3a4h3i 3k2j2h ikl 6w4e2t`

Now, I'd like to decompress the output - back to original.

And I am struggling with this since a couple days now.

My idea so far:

```
void Decompress(std::string &compressed, std::string &original)
{
    char currentChar = 0;
    auto n = compressed.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        currentChar = compressed[i++];

        if(compressed[i] <= 1) {
            original += compressed[i];
        } else if (isalpha(currentChar)) {
            //
        } else {
            //
            int number = isnumber(currentChar).....
            original += number;
        }
    }
}
```

I know my Decompress function seems a bit messy, but I am pretty lost with this one.
Sorry for that.

Maybe there is someone out there at stackoverflow who would like to help a lost and beginner soul.

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it.

Comment: `original += number;`? What does `isnumber()`? However, you should convert the digit char(s) into a number, store that into a variable (e.g. `number`), read the next char from `compressed` and add that char `number` times to `original`, shouldn't you?

Comment: What I don't get: `if(compressed[i] <= 1) {
            original += compressed[i]; }` What do you intend to achieve with this code?

Comment: Maybe, a missing piece: integers and digit chars are something different. So, if you convert `(int)3` to a string (e.g. with `std::to_string()`) you will get `"3"` where the char `3` is stored as value 51 (0x33). That's because the string (conversion) considers [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding (probably). To convert a number string back to an `int`, you have to reverse this. For single digits, this could be `c - '0'` but you could use `std::istringstream` or [std::stoi()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) as well.

Comment: Hi Scheff! Thank you for your help! Ok, so my idea was, if I only have a single char (not compressed) just hand it over to original. Otherwerwise, check if there if there is a number. If there is a number check the character after number and print the count. This is more or less my idea.

Comment: I would drop this. First, this code does not what you intend. Second, I don't see the necessity to handle a special case of a one character string. For what?

Comment: What would you replace for `//` in `if (isalpha(currentChar)) { // }`?

Comment: Well, honestly I don't know. I am really struggling with this. Compressing was not so hard, but Decompressing.. totally different story for me as a beginner. The function above is just an idea of how I thought It could somehow work, u know. Your very first comment - I will try that out!

Comment: You encoding is already flawed. Imagine you have to encode string 333a, then you'd write 33a. But how could you ever know if you original code now was 333a or consisted of a string containing 33 times the value a???

Comment: While trying myself (just for fun), I noticed that `isalpha()` is a bad choice. Please, note that there are spaces in your sample which are not considered as alphas. I would suggest to use `isdigit()` to separated digits from the rest (and assume that digits may not appear as raw text  in your sample for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "string"
#include "iostream"


void Encode(std::string& inputstring, std::string& outputstring)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inputstring.length(); i++) {
        int count = 1;
        while (inputstring[i] == inputstring[i + 1]) {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        if (count <= 1) {
            outputstring += inputstring[i];
        }
        else {
            outputstring += std::to_string(count);
            outputstring += inputstring[i];
        }
    }
}

bool alpha_or_space(const char c)
{
    return isalpha(c) || c == ' ';
}

void Decompress(std::string& compressed, std::string& original)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t repeat;
    while (i < compressed.length())
    {
        // normal alpha charachers
        while (alpha_or_space(compressed[i]))
            original.push_back(compressed[i++]);

        // repeat number
        repeat = 0;
        while (isdigit(compressed[i]))
            repeat = 10 * repeat + (compressed[i++] - '0');

        // unroll releat charachters
        auto char_to_unroll = compressed[i++];
        while (repeat--)
            original.push_back(char_to_unroll);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string deco, outp, inp = "aaahhhhiii kkkjjhh ikl wwwwwweeeett";

    Encode(inp, outp);
    Decompress(outp, deco);

    std::cout << inp << std::endl << outp << std::endl<< deco;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you might have UB here: `while (alpha_or_space(compressed[i])) \\ original.push_back(compressed[i++]);`

Comment: @Damien, why is that UB?

Comment: If  `i` is equal to its max value, after `i++`, the next test `while(...)` is performed with a too large `i` value

Comment: it all runs under the ' while (i < compressed.length())' check, and 'while (alpha_or_space(compressed[i]))' will exit when reaching the null terminator.

Comment: Effectively I forgot that since C++11, `std::string`  is guaranteed to end with the null terminator.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming input strings cannot contain digits (this cannot be covered by your encoding as e. g. both the strings `"3a"` and `"aaa"` would result in the encoded string `"3a"` – how would you ever want to decompose again?) then you can decompress as follows:

```
unsigned int num = 0;
for(auto c : compressed)
{
    if(std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)))
    {
        num = num * 10 + c - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        num += num == 0; // assume you haven't read a digit yet!
        while(num--)
        {
            original += c;
        }
    }
}
```

Untested code, though...

Characters in a string actually are only numerical values, though. You can consider `char` (or `signed char`, `unsigned char`) as ordinary 8-bit integers as well. And you can store a numerical value in such a byte, too. Usually, you do run length encoding exactly that way: Count up to 255 equal characters, store the count in a single byte and the character in another byte. One single `"a"` would then be encoded as `0x01 0x61` (the latter being the ASCII value of `a`), `"aa"` would get `0x02 0x61`, and so on. If you have to store more than 255 equal characters you store two pairs: `0xff 0x61, 0x07 0x61` for a string containing 262 times the character `a`... Decoding then gets trivial: you read characters pairwise, first byte you interpret as number, second one as character – rest being trivial. And you nicely cover digits that way as well.

Comment: Just close to that with what I came up: [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3aedd001ba45077). ;-) (The previous attempt was buggy.)

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why you multiply num by 10? has something do you with the ASCII table? (new line feed)?

Comment: @liasis Assume you have counted 27 times the letter a. Then you first read digit `2` as ASCII value (thus you subtract '0' to get numerical value), thus you store 2. In next loop run you do `2 * 10 + 7` to get the value 27 back. For very first digit, you do `0*10 + 2` actually...

Answer (score 0):

The decompression can't possibly work in an unambiguous way because you didn't define a sentinel character; i.e. given the compressed stream it's impossible to determine whether a number is an original single number or it represents the repeat RLE command. I would suggest using '0' as the sentinel char. While encoding, if you see '0' you just output `010`. Any other char X will translate to `0NX` where `N` is the repeat byte counter. If you go over 255, just output a new RLE repeat command